# SQl shorhand for and condition

Tags: mysql, jpql, relational-division

i'm facing a problem with sql queries... is there a shorthand for AND condition  like IN= many OR conditions??
when not, any idea about this situation. considering we have 2 tables student and topics with many to many relation.

Problem:   get all student who choose topic a And b And c.
Note: the list of topics in not fixe.
Table: student

| student | studentID |
| --- | --- |
| w | 1 |
| x | 2 |
| y | 3 |
| z | 4 |

Table: Topic

| topic | topicID |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| e | 4 |
| f | 5 |
| g | 6 |
| h | 7 |
| i | 8 |

Table: StudentTopic

| studentID | TopicID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 6 |

That is what i tried: **select *** **from **student **where ** topic **in** (a,b,c).
the result is not correct because know that IN is the shorthand for many OR conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no shorthand in SQL for this.

Generally, it's called [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division). This is to fit it into the algebra metaphor to form a counter to the JOIN operation, which could be the analog of multiplication in arithmetic.

Because relational division is less commonly used than join, the SQL language does not provide a very easy shorthand. You can get the result you want, but it's not as quick as using JOIN.

```
SELECT studentId
FROM StudentTopic
WHERE topicId IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY studentId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT topicId) = 3;
```

There are other ways to get the same result, for example:

```
SELECT s1.studentId
FROM StudentTopic AS s1
INNER JOIN StudentTopic AS s2 USING (studentId)
INNER JOIN StudentTopic AS s3 USING (studentId)
WHERE s1.topicId = 1
  AND s2.topicId = 2
  AND s3.topicId = 3;
```

You can follow the [relational-division](/questions/tagged/relational-division) tag to read about other solutions. But none of them are very simple. It's just not an operation that has been given special shorthand syntax in SQL.